# Is this should used for suggestion?

Tags: modal-verbs

> “I won't let you do it," he [= Neville] said, hurrying to stand in
>   front of the portrait hole. "I'll –– I'll fight you [Harry, Ron, and
>   Hermione]!" 
>       "Neville," Ron exploded, "get away from that hole and don't be an idiot 
>       ––" "Don't you call me an idiot!" said Neville. I don't think you **should** be breaking any more rules! And you were the one who told me to stand up to people!" 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

Is the ‘should’ the one that is ‘used after *that* when something is suggested or arranged’ (OALD.[should](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/should).8) as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really necessary to look beyond [AOLD's first definition](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/should) for this specific usage...

> **1** used to show what is right, appropriate, etc, especially when criticizing somebody's actions
>   *You **shouldn't** drink and drive.*
>   *He **should** have been more careful.*